# Forwarding incoming Google Cloud Platform traffic to an external host

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I was trying out Google Container Engine to test some Docker hosts and decided to just keep running them on my own cluster for now. I've switched DNS over, but I'd like to forward any remaining traffic from stragglers (due to DNS caching on clients) over to my own cluster.

What's the best way to proxy this traffic to my own hosts? I have a Static IP pointed to a Forwarding Rule currently so I'm hoping I can just apply that IP to a Load Balancer, but all the online docs are targeted towards forwarding traffic *within* GCP.

Of course I could just run an HAProxy container which in turn forwards that traffic on to my own cluster but I'm hoping there's an easier way?

Comment: I can't think of any out of the box solution available on Google Cloud to forward the requests to your own cluster. HAproxy seems to be a good solution for your setup. You can also try iptable to redirect the traffic from  VM node to your own host.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? If so please consider posting a self-answer so the community can benefit.